# Finding data in urlib .read()

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

after conducting a .read() from urllib  I am not able to search for strings in the response.

Using

```
response = urlopen(req).read()
    if str(response).find(someString) != -1 :
        print ("Success")
    else:
        print ("Fail")
```

I always get fail.

However using the standard
    if someString in str(response):

I always get Success

when I perform a print the str(response) I can see whether the string exists or not so I know that neither function is working correctly.  Does Python handle the .read() response differently for print than it does for string searches? If so what should I be using to search the response from .read() with?

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the answer in searching through other issues with urllib.

The issue comes down to the `.read()` function returns in byte format.  So in order to search you must instead you must change the encoding.  Since the data I am reading always returns the character set I used the following code:

```
response = urlopen(req)
out = response.read().decode(response.headers.get_content_charset())

if out.find( someString ) != -1:
    print ( "Success" )
else:
    print ( "Fail" )
```

If the headers being received did not contain the charset then it can be designated instead of pulling from the headers.  I expect I can now even switch back to the standard `if someString in out:` format.